# How to upload an image in the plugin's options page

Tags: media-library, uploads

My code is here.The other options working perfectly so how i can register the image and save the link in database and image in wp library.

```
function register_team_show_case_setting() {
    //register our settings
        register_setting('my_team_show_case_setting', 'layout');
        register_setting('my_team_show_case_setting', 'color');

        register_setting('my_team_show_case_setting', 'image');
}
function submenu_callback() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Team Showcase Setting</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('my_team_show_case_setting'); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections('my_team_show_case_setting'); ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Layout</th>
                    <td> 
                        <select class="select-box" name="layout" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('layout')); ?> class="form-control">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="Grid"  <?php if (get_option('layout') == "Grid") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Grid</option>
                            <option value="Grid-without-tab"  <?php if (get_option('layout') == "Grid-without-tab") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Grid-without-tab</option>
                            <option value="Row" <?php if (get_option('layout') == "Row") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Row</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Color Schema</th>
                    <td> 
                        <select class="select-box" name="color" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_option('color')); ?> class="form-control">
                            <option value="orange" <?php if (get_option('color') == "orange") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >orange</option>
                            <option value="green" <?php if (get_option('color') == "green") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>green</option>
                            <option value="blue" <?php if (get_option('color') == "blue") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>blue</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Background Image</th>       
                     <td> 
                     <input type="file" name="image" />

                    </td> 
                </tr> 

            </table>
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Hi, first thing I notice is that you registered 'image' but used a name for the field of 'logo'

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook i am not asking about spelling. i need functionality

Comment: Well if they don't match how can WP know what to do with the input?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook i have lot of code there thats why i have removed all of it and left this one. So its honest mistake  while asking question.very disappoint to mins the secore

Comment: The minus wasn't me

Comment: than sory and love you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40424/discussion-between-sajid-and-andy-macaulay-brook).

Answer (score 9):

The better title for this would be: How to use the WordPress media uploader to upload images into settings page.

1- Add the necessary scripts to show the media uploader:

```
add_action('admin_footer', function() { 

    /*
    if possible try not to queue this all over the admin by adding your settings GET page val into next
    if( empty( $_GET['page'] ) || "my-settings-page" !== $_GET['page'] ) { return; }
    */

    ?>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            var custom_uploader
              , click_elem = jQuery('.wpse-228085-upload')
              , target = jQuery('.wrap input[name="logo"]')

            click_elem.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
                if (custom_uploader) {
                    custom_uploader.open();
                    return;
                }
                //Extend the wp.media object
                custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                    title: 'Choose Image',
                    button: {
                        text: 'Choose Image'
                    },
                    multiple: false
                });
                //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
                custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
                    attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                    target.val(attachment.url);
                });
                //Open the uploader dialog
                custom_uploader.open();
            });      
        });
    </script>

    <?php
    });
```

2- Embed the media uploader necessary scripts:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    /*
    if possible try not to queue this all over the admin by adding your settings GET page val into next
    if( empty( $_GET['page'] ) || "my-settings-page" !== $_GET['page'] ) { return; }
    */
    wp_enqueue_media();
});
```

3- Now add a clickable button next to your image field to call the media uploader:

```
<input type="file" name="logo" />
<button class="button wpse-228085-upload">Upload</button>
```

Once the uploader is working, you can now process the image field (`input[name="logo"]`) like any other settings field and save its value to your options.

Hope that helps.